# FTCS Algorithm for the heat equation

Tags: python, physics, pde

I am attempting to implement the FTCS algorithm for the 1 dimensional heat equation in Python.

```
import numpy as np

L = 1 #Length of rod in x direction
k = 0.3 #Thermal conductivity of rod
tmax = 5 #how many seconds
nx = 100 #number of spacial steps
nt = 100; #number of time steps
xi = np.linspace(0,L,nx) 
ti = np.linspace(0,tmax,nt)
dx = L/(nx-1)
dt = tmax/(nt-1)
r = k*dt/(dx)**2
r2 = 1-2*r

u=np.zeros((nt,nx))
#IC
phi = 100;
for x in range(0,nx):    
    u[0][x] = phi

#BC
for t in range(0,nt):    
    u[t][0] = 0;
    u[t][nx-1] = 0
#FTCS Algorithm

for t in range(0,nt-1): #timestep
    for x in range(1,nx-2):
        u[t+1][x] = r*(u[t][x-1]+ u[t][x+1]) + r2*(u[t][x])
```

However I am not getting plausible values for u[t][x] = u(x,t) considering my initial conditions of 100. i.e. they blow up and give me stupid values like '4.11052068e+221' is there some bad programming practise I am partaking in which is destroying the algorithm? Or have I just implemented the algorithm incorrectly?

EDIT: I think I have worked out that it is because the algorithm is stable if and only if r < 1/2. The numbers just blow up because my r is about 2.5 or whatever, however if anyone can see any other errors let me know!!

Answer (score 1):

**Original Question**

The stability of the FTCS scheme hinges on the size of the constant `r`. If `r<1/2`, then rounding errors introduced at each step will exponentially decay. If `r>1/2`, then those rounding errors will exponentially increase. (As you've alluded to in your edit).

**Small-ish Errors**

1. `dx = L/nx` and `dt = tmax/nt`. (If this is confusing to you, imagine the case of `nx = 2` and `L = 1`...
   then `dx = 0.5`).
2. `L` and `tmax` should be floats. (ie - `L = 1.0`).
3. You are not updating the temperature `u` at the second to last position on the rod. Make sure the for loop over position extends to `nx-1` and NOT `nx-2`.

**Things to consider**

4. You might consider using real values/units for time, length, thermal conductivity and initial temperature.
5. When you apply the boundary conditions (under the comment #BC), only the time `t=0` has values of `u` which are non-zero, so you do not need to iterate through all the time steps.
6. While it is necessary for you to iterate through time (hence the time `for` loop), you can actually vectorize the spatial derivative. You could replace your for loop with the following:

   `for t in range(0, nt-1):
       u[t+1, 1:nx-1] = r*(u[t,0:nx-2] + u[t,2:]) + r2*(u[t,1:nx-1])`